# Serializing associated entity in odata response

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

The problem is field `Address` is not being returned in o-data get call on entity set `TestEntity` without the `$expand` clause, while in the code I am assigning the valid `Address` object to it .

We already had an o-data entity exposed through web-API

```
public class TestEntity
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string A { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Val { get; set; }
}
```

And later on we decided to expose Address also as an entity, and we added a key and a controller for `Address`, where clients can create address and associate it with other entities. But as `Address` was changed, it is no longer being returned as part of `TestEntity` class. On searching the web I found, since `Address` is now a navigation property it is not returned by default, clients need to send `$expand`  clause. But we don't want to break existing clients, therefore we need to return without clients sending `$expand` clause on it. How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Microsoft.AspNet.OData](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.OData/) version 5.7 or greater, than you can annotate the `Address` property with the [`AutoExpand`](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#04-15-autoexpand-attribute) attribute.

Comment: Unfortunately it is an older version 5.3, I can't change the version.

Comment: Then you'll need to add code to manually retrieve the Address object inside the `Get` method of your `EntitiesController`.

Comment: In my class I have added code to read 'Address' and filled in the TestEntity, but the problem is web API is not serializing that value. On the wire I can see there is no value being serialized for 'Address'

Comment: OK, that's a different problem. You should pot a new question with sample code showing what you've tried.